# Vim lookup help for visual mode key bindings

Tags: vim, key-bindings

When I'm not sure what a key does in Vim I type in the help command.

e.g.

```
:help u
```

It shows me what key 'u' does in normal mode (undo).

**What is the command to get help for 'u' in visual mode?**

I'm asking because I stumbled upon this 'u' in visual model (selected text becomes lowercase), but I would like to know how to look up help for visual mode key bindings.

Comment: Come on, everything is explained in the first screen when you do `:help`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, visual mode key bindings are tagged with `v_` prefix, so you can find help for `u` in visual mode like `:h v_u`.

Comment: How about to lookup help for keys with modifiers? Like Ctrl-m?

Comment: You can achieve that with `:h CTRL-M`.
However this looks up helps for normal mode only, so you need to prefix for looking up helps for other modes, insert and visual.
The prefix follows the same rule as I answered above, so the prefix for insert mode is `i_` and visual mode is `v_`
For example, to look up help Control + T in INSERT mode is `:h i_CTRL-T`.